# C# excel interop formula dragging

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm using the C# excel interop framework to automating generate a bunch of reports for my company and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do equation dragging with this.

If I could do this with a named range this would be even better, but even if I have to hard code the rows so it's along the lines of drag A10:J10 down to A20:J20 this would probably be ok.

Even any pointers to a webpage explaining how to do this would be much appreciated as I'm kind of stuck on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Range object has a method called AutoFill, you should try that.

```
range.AutoFill(destinationRange);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next snippet. Hope be helpful

```
Excel.Range r1 = xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[offset , 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[offset, 1]];
Excel.Range r2 = xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[offset, 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[offset + 10, 1]];
r1.AutoFill(r2, Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this not that long ago. Here's an example of my code:

```
Excel.Range rng, rngResize;
rng = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range("A10", "J10");
rngResize = rng.get_Resize(10, Missing.Value);
rngResize.Formula = "=B9+I8";
```

The formula is applied relatively. And I used separate variables for each step so they can be `Disposed`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_resize(VS.80).aspx which says that the function isn't supposed to be used directly from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Excel table (ListObject) by invoking the Add method of the [ListObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.listobjects.aspx) collection of the Worksheet object. This is the equivalent of using the "Format as table" command in Excel. Any equation entered in a table row will auto-fill to all rows of the table using relative references to table columns. This behavior is on by default but can be controlled by the setting at

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists
```